# How to use jQuery to select divs that do not have tr tags with a specific id in them

Tags: jquery-selectors

Here's some sample code to explain what I'm trying to do:

```
<div id="list_subpanel_contacts">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr class="oddListRowS1"></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="list_subpanel_accounts_usi_orders">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="list_subpanel_orders">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr class="oddListRowS1"></tr>
            <tr class="evenListRowS1"></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I need to find any div with an id **starting with** "list_subpanel_", and **doesn't** have any `<tr`> tags that have a class of either "oddListRowS1" or "evenListRowS1".

Then I need to get whatever is after the second underscore in the div's id and pass that to a function.

So, in the code example, the jQuery would find just the second div and pass "accounts_usi_orders" to the function.

This is pretty far beyond my current jQuery selection knowledge, so I'd appreciate any help, guys. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
var divs = $("div[id^=list_subpanel_]").filter(function() {
    return !$(this).find("tr.oddListRowS1, tr.evenListRowS1").length;
});
```

To extract the `id` fragment, you can use [substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

```
divs.each(function() {
    yourFunction(this.id.substr(14));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements = new Array();

var i = 0;

    $("div[id^='list_subpanel_']").each(function(){
        if($(this).find('tr.oddListRowS1,tr.evenListRowS1').attr("class") == undefined){
           elements[i] = $(this);
           i++;
        }
    });

    for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        $(elements[i]).attr("id","whatever");  //And then do what you want to do with it
    }
```